# How to make a DateTime object immutable (declare as const) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, constants, immutability

I have attempted the following code which will not work

```
private const DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

to which the compiler states "DateTime variable cannot be declared as const".

I am wondering how to make this object immutable, as i do not want to be able to change it anywhere by mistake.  This value will be used as a check value to compare other DateTime objects to.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried making it readonly?

Comment: I have not yet, that is a good idea.  Thank you

Comment: is there anyway to avoid setting it in the constructor?

Comment: You should be able to set it where it's declared.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make it static and mark with `readonly` keyword, i.e.:

```
private static readonly DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

Comment: Note that the one drawback here is that technically it could be modified in that class's constructor, or through unsafe/reflection shenanigans.

Comment: @xbonez `const` variables are implicitly `static`, so if he wanted it to be `const` it's clearly not an instance specific variable.  As far as true implications, it means the variable is stored once, not per instance.  If it's always the same, that's saving memory.

Comment: @Servy - "modified in that class's constructor" - not possible, once marked `static readonly` and given a initial value. static constructor can change it yes.

Comment: is there anyway to avoid setting it in the constructor?

Comment: @weston If it's non-static you can modify it in the constructor.  If static you can modify it in the static constructor.  Just try it out for yourself; it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: @jordan.peoples This will do it. Try it, it won't compile if you do.

Comment: @jordan.peoples There is no way to prevent it from being set in a constructor, no, you just need to know not to do it, and not let anyone else do it.  Sorry.  You could of course have a VS script, check in validation for TFS, or other external code validation rule of some sort that enforces that restriction.

Comment: @Servy yes, I realised that, doing too much java recently, it doesn't allow `final`s to be assigned more than once anywhere.

Comment: @jordan.peoples - encapsulation is to protect the object from external influences at runtime, you can't protect the code from being edited, e.g. there is nothing to stop them removing the `readonly`. If concerned, I suggest unit tests are best way to ensure class works way you intended in the future.

Comment: @weston Agreed, I forgot to mention that.  A unit test that verifies that the constant value is what it should have been initialized will go a long way towards preventing developers accidentally changing it in the constructor.